# Sigma notation abstract limits

Tags: notation, summation

What is meant by the following  notations? $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{p+1}k^3$, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{p-2}k^3$ I need to use this notation to prove a statement is true for $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{p+1}k^3$ when $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{p}k^3$ is already proved, and other situations alike.

Is there a consistent documentation of the notation used in mathematics, which people have agreed on? Either a book or an online resource recommendation would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the notation is consistent. The following: $$S=\sum_{k=n_1}^{n_2} f\left(k\right)$$ means precisely: $$S= f\left(n_1\right) +  f\left(n_1+1\right) + \cdots +  f\left(n_2-1\right) +  f\left(n_2\right)$$

In your case, we have:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{p+1} k^3 = 0^3 + 1^3 + \cdots + p^3 + \left(p+1\right)^3$$

You might want to use the following property when trying to prove what you want:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{p+1}k^3 =\sum_{k=0}^{p}k^3 + \left(p+1\right)^3 $$

which means that:

$$\left[0^3 + 1^3 + \cdots + p^3\right] + \left(p+1\right)^3 =
\left[0^3 + 1^3 + \cdots + p^3 + \left(p+1\right)^3\right]$$

---

I should also mention that sometimes, when the set of values that we want $k$ to range over is not of the form $\left\{n_1,n_1+1,\ldots,n_2\right\}$, we use the following notation: $$S= \sum_{k\in A} f\left(k\right)$$ to mean that we want the sum for all $k$ in the set $A$.

For instance, if $A$ is the set of prime numbers less than $10$, $A=\left\{2,3,5,7\right\}$, we will write:
$$\sum_{k\in A} k^3 = 2^3 + 3^3 + 5^3 + 7^3$$

Comment: Could you please include the case of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{p-2}$?

Comment: If you can't work it out, it means you didn't understand what I wrote. Which part are you having trouble?

Comment: I need to work out precisely what this notation means. $\sum\limits_{k=n_2}^{n_2}$ what is the increment?

Comment: The third formula I wrote didn't help you? What do you understand from it?

Comment: It means to me begin iterating over k, start with k=0 and iterate with increment +1. Stop when k=p+1.

Comment: The increment is always one, when the notation is this. (exactly like you just wrote. But we usually refer to the operation "substitute $k$ by $k+1$" as "increment $1$", and not "increment $k+1$")

Comment: What set of numbers are you using for the iteration process to specify the increment, which is the default one, and how to specify it explicitly? Is there a way to specify the increment explicitly?

Comment: Yes, I've just added it to the answer

Comment: Is there a way to iterate over a set starting with a random index and increment the index each time by a random number from this set? For example to show no matter how you sum something up it will be a certain value within a very specific set?

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you wrote, but you can make up a sequence $k_n$ of values you want $k$ to assume (in whatever order you like), and then write your sum as $\sum_{n=1}^N f\left(k_n\right)$